# What is the difference between monerod --detach and monerod --non-interactive?

Tags: monerod, daemon, operating-system

It seems like each of these would run `monerod` in the background.  How does the behavior differ?  Under what circumstances might one choose `--detached` over `--non-interactive` or vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `--detach` will run the daemon in the background. `--non-interactive` will run in the foreground but the daemon will not require a Terminal for input.

Quoting from [monerodocs monerod reference](https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monerod-reference/):

- `--detach`

  > Go to background (decouple from the terminal). This is useful for long-running / server scenarios. Typically, you will also want to manage monerod daemon with systemd or similar. By default monerod runs in a foreground.
- `--non-interactive`

  > Do not require tty in a foreground mode. Helpful when running in a container. By default monerod runs in a foreground and opens stdin for reading. This breaks containerization because no tty gets assigned and monerod process crashes. You can make it run in a background with --detach but this is inconvenient in a containerized environment because the canonical usage is that the container waits on the main process to exist (forking makes things more complicated).

Comment: Do you know if commands can be sent to it while it's in non-interactive mode?  When just "detached," `monerod status` will return the same as would print out if you enter `status` in a normal/attached daemon window. I haven't been able to figure out how to pass commands successfully to monerod when it's in non-interactive mode though.

Comment: The same should work in `--non-interactive` mode.